# How to get a backbone model's ID on the server upon model's destruction

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, express

I'm trying to use a Backbone model in my Marionette application. I have a collection view which correctly displays all entries I have for a specific model. The item view contains a delete button. It listens for clicks on that button, calling a delete function when such a click occurs:

```
events: {
    'click .deleteItem': 'deleteItem'
},
deleteItem: function (event) {
    console.log('id', this.model.id);
    this.model.destroy({ wait: true });

}
```

`this.model.destroy` correctly make a DELETE request to the `myModel/` url, but it doesn't seem to include any information on which entry is to be delete. For example, on the server side (a Node.js server), I don't see anything in req.body (yes, I'm using the body parser). How do I get the id of the entry I'm trying to delete when responding to the DELETE request on the server side?

Note: I can get it easily enough on the client side: `this.model.id`

Comment: Can you not get it from the route parameters?

Comment: @moderndegree How? If I `app.delete('/myModel/:id', func...)`, I get a 404 error for `/myModel`.

Comment: And if I set the model's url to `/myModel/:id`, it sends the DELETE request to `/mymodel/:id` instead of replacing `:id` with the actual ID of the to-be-deleted entry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the route parameters:

```
app.delete('/thing/:id', function(req, res){
    console.log('deleting ' + req.params.id); 
});
```

Then your model would look like this:

```
var ThingModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    idAttribute: '_id', // or whatever your id attribute is
    urlRoot: '/thing'
});
```

Then you would delete it like so:

```
var someThing = new ThingModel({_id:123, foo:'bar'});
someThing.destroy();
```

It sounds like you did not declare the `urlRoot` of your model. Read up on it [here](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-urlRoot).

Comment: No, to what should I set urlRoot?

Comment: in this case, `urlRoot` would be `/myModel` and should be declared in your model definition. Check my example.

Comment: Thanks, replacing `url: '/myModel'` with `urlRoot: '/myModel'` did the trick :)